# investigated by descartes rule of sign

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, quartics

Use Descartes' rules of signs to discuss and determine (how many) the number of possible positive roots of each equation.
$p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$

Comment: Hi, could you present your attempts ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Not only have you shown no work, it looks like you forgot to show the whole question. There's not a lot you can do with Descartes' rule when you don't have any coefficients with known signs.

Answer (score -1):

Descartes' rules of signs can be used to determine the number of positive and negative roots of a polynomial equation in one variable with real coefficients, without actually solving the equation.

Rule 1: The number of positive roots of the polynomial equation p(x) = 0 is either equal to the number of sign changes between consecutive nonzero coefficients of p(x) or less than that by an even number.

Rule 2: The number of negative roots of the polynomial equation p(-x) = 0 is either equal to the number of sign changes between consecutive nonzero coefficients of p(-x) or less than that by an even number.

Using these rules, we can analyze the possibilities for the roots of the given equation p(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0:

- If all coefficients of p(x) have the same sign, then p(x) has no positive roots.
- If the coefficients of p(x) alternate in sign, then p(x) may have one or three positive roots.
- If the coefficients of p(x) have more than one change of sign, then p(x) may have two or four positive roots, depending on the number of sign changes.
- If all coefficients of p(-x) have the same sign, then p(x) has no negative roots.
- If the coefficients of p(-x) alternate in sign, then p(x) may have one or three negative roots.
- If the coefficients of p(-x) have more than one change of sign, then p(x) may have two or four negative roots, depending on the number of sign changes.

Note that Descartes' rules of signs only give information about the possible number of positive and negative roots of a polynomial equation, not their exact values or multiplicities. To determine the actual roots of the equation, one would need to use other methods such as factoring, the rational root theorem, or numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering to this question. Could you use Mathjax environment to put equation in math mod ? ( use \$ \$)